# Vlookup that skips #N/A values

Tags: excel, vlookup

In Sheet1!B, I am doing a `vlookup` in `Sheet2!A2:B100` which searches for the value in Sheet1!A and returns the value in Sheet2!B.

E.g., in `Sheet1!B2`:

```
=Vlookup(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$100,2,false)
```

Some of the values in Sheet1!A repeat in Sheet2!A, but some of the corresponding values in Sheet2!B are `#N/A`, hence some of outputs in Sheet1!B are also `#N/A` when that `#N/A` is the first value the formula finds.

How can I adjust the formula to skip those `#N/A`s and return the first non-error response? Open to using `index-match` or `sumproduct`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a concrete sample it is difficult to provide an answer, but I guess you can try the following:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$B$100, 
 NOT(ISNA(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100))),2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,FILTER(Sheet2!$A$2:$B$100, 
 1-ISNA(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100)),2,FALSE)
```